How to transfer the GeoTIFF coordinates to pixel values
I have a function to convert the pixel values to the coordinates using the ground control points from the GeoTIFF file, which is given as below:
import rasterio.control
import rasterio.transform

def transform_pixel_to_coordinate_with_gcps(
    gcps: list[rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint],
    pixel_x: float,
    pixel_y: float,
):
    lon, lat = rasterio.transform.xy(transform=gcps, rows=pixel_y, cols=pixel_x)
    return float(lon), float(lat)

This function works well. As an example, the two red points in the figure blew are transferred from the pixel values of the centre points of the two shining areas nearby.

I was trying to use another function to transfer the coordinates to pixel values. The function is given as follows:
def transform_coordinate_to_pixel_with_gcps(
    gcps: list[rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint],
    lon: float,
    lat: float,
):
    affine_transform = rasterio.transform.from_gcps(gcps=gcps)
    pixel_y, pixel_x = rasterio.transform.rowcol(
        transform=affine_transform, xs=lon, ys=lat
    )
    return pixel_x, pixel_y

When I tested this function together with the first function, I notice something strange. The image below shows an example from the test.

The expected value of pixel_x and pixel_y in the test should be around 275 and 1361, respectively. Since the attempt of the test is to transfer the pixel values to coordinates and then transfer it back. However, we can see that the final result is far away from the original pixel values. How did it happen and how can I get the expected result?
I modified the function later as below to do the coordinates-pixel transformation:
def transform_pixel_to_coordinate_with_gcps_2(
    gcps: list[rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint],
    pixel_x: float,
    pixel_y: float,
):
    affine_transform = rasterio.transform.from_gcps(gcps=gcps)
    lon, lat = rasterio.transform.xy(
        transform=affine_transform, rows=pixel_y, cols=pixel_x
    )
    return float(lon), float(lat)

This function works well with the second function:

As can be seen, the expected result was obtained in the test. However, if you compare the coordinates from the function transform_pixel_to_coordinate_with_gcps and function transform_pixel_to_coordinate_with_gcps_2, there is actually a big difference. In the image blew, the green points are the result from transform_pixel_to_coordinate_with_gcps_2. Therefore, due to the consideration of accuracy, I prefer using the ground control points directly to conduct the transformation, like the first function does. In this case, how can I transfer the coordinates to the pixel values in the case that the CRS can not be found in the GeoTIFF (only the GCPS can be found)?


I realised that the transform of the rasterio.transform.rowcol can also use the ground control points. So the function can be modified as:
def transform_coordinate_to_pixel_with_gcps_2(
    gcps: list[rasterio.control.GroundControlPoint],
    lon: float,
    lat: float,
):
    pixel_y, pixel_x = rasterio.transform.rowcol(
        transform=gcps, xs=lon, ys=lat
    )
    return pixel_x, pixel_y

In the test, this function gives better result than transform_coordinate_to_pixel_with_gcps when working with the first function:

As the conclusion, when the pixel values are transferred to coordinates using the ground control points directly (like the first function in the question), in order to transfer the coordinates back to the pixel values, the ground control points may also need to be used directly (like the function in this answer).
However, I am still looking forward to the solution which can give more accurate result.
